# SQL Paramaters in FoxPro 2.6 DOS

Tags: sql, dos, foxpro

In FoxPro 2.6 for MS-DOS is there a way to use a variable in a SELECT command? For example, how can I write the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM DBFILE WHERE Ord_no = temp_no
```

Given that temp_no is a previously defined variable. I tried using "&temp_no" but this does not appear to be the correct syntax.

Comment: What is MS-DOS? 

Try dropping the &. I was told SELECT * FROM DBFILE WHERE Ord_no = temp_no should work.(I asked the foxpro devs, I don't know myself.)

Comment: What is MS-DOS? Man, I'm old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct, and you shouldn't need to macro it via the "&".  What may be failing is due to data types.  If your table "dbfile", column "ord_no" is numeric and your variable "temp_no" is a character string, that would fail due to a data type mismatch... make sure they are the same data type... again, REGARDLESS of using the "&" macro.

MyVarOrd_No = 23

select * from DBFile where Ord_No = MyVarOrd_No

or if a string/charcter based column, just change

MyVarOrd_No = "23"
However you may need to pad with spaces/justify if its being picky.

Comment: It looks like a blank record was causing the problem. In a blank record the field value would be the null string which cannot be compared to a string. So it was a data type problem.

Answer (score 0):

[The microsoft line on using variables in foxpro](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114670).